# Merge the first element of two different arrays into one array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have:

data_x = [0,1,2,3]

data_y = [4,5,6,7]

and I need the final result to be:

s_o_rms = [(0,4),(1,5),(2,6),(3,7)]

Till now I tried:

'''

```
    i = 0
    j = 0
    s_o_rms = []

    for i in data_x:
        for j in data_y:
            s_o_rms.append(data_x(i)+','+data_y(i))
            i = i + 1
            j = j + 1
    print(s_o_rms)
```

'''

However I am getting an Error: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable.
Any idea of how I can solve this problem? or maybe another method I can use to obtain the needed result?

Note: data_x and data_y actually have 68 elements each, which is why I am using for loops but for the sake of explaining my problem I'm using a smaller array

Comment: You should be using `data_x[]`, not `data_x()`. But take a look at [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: In **Numpy** just do `s_o_rms = np.concatenate((data_x, data_y), axis=0)`. If using regular lists and not **Numpy** arrays, then you don't need **Numpy** and can just use **zip**.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s_o_rms = []

for i,j in zip(data_x,data_y):
            s_o_rms.append((i,j))

print(s_o_rms)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try list comprehension

Result = [(data_x[index], data_y[index]) for index in range(Len(data_x))]

And someone mentioned it, zip() is another easy way